# How to parent/connect/attach rigid body objects to a moving rig?

Tags: rigging, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I need cannonballs to follow a moving cannon. The cannonballs are rigid body objects parented to an empty. The empty is parented to the rig (Parent type: Armature)
When the rig is staying near the origin point of the rig, the cannonballs are launched perfectly, but when the rig is moving further away from its origin point the cannonballs do not follow and drop out of the barrel.

When I change the parent type of the Empty to Bone and select the bone: Cannon_Barrel, and run the simulation. The cannonballs follow the rig but won’t interact with the simulation anymore.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to go is to use the child of constraint.

The cannonball has this constraint to the cannon.

I keyframed the influence to that value to 1 before firing and to 0 at firing.

On the same frame i changed the rigid body animated checkbox from 1 to 0.

And of course i changed at that frame the strength of my force field from 0 to 10000.

result:

[image]

[image]

```
This will work with armatures as well. If you want a "special" solution for your armature, please provide your blend file.
```